# nested dict sum values in python

Tags: python

you can see file A like that:

```
LOC_Os06g07630.1 cyto 8, chlo 2, extr 2, nucl 1, cysk 1, chlo_mito 1, cysk_nucl 1
LOC_Os06g12160.1 chlo 7, nucl 3, mito 2.5, cyto_mito 2
LOC_Os06g39870.1 chlo 7, cyto 4, nucl 1, E.R. 1, pero 1
LOC_Os06g48240.1 chlo 9, mito 4
LOC_Os06g48250.1 cyto 5, chlo 4, mito 2, pero 2
```

i care about "chlo" and "chlo_mito" and "mito" ,and sum values in every row

like row LOC_Os06g07630.1,i will use chlo 2 and chlo_mito 1,
the sum values is 3=(chlo)2+(chlo_mito)1

the row sum values is

(cyto)8+(chlo)2+(extr)2+(nucl)1+(cysk)1+(chlo_mito)1+(cysk_nucl)1=16,and then print 3/16

I want to get next contents:

```
LOC_Os06g07630.1 chlo 2 chlo_mito 1 3/16
LOC_Os06g12160.1 chlo 7 mito 2.5 9.5/14.5
LOC_Os06g39870.1 chlo 7 7/15
LOC_Os06g48240.1 chlo 9 mito 4 13/13
LOC_Os06g48250.1 chlo 4 mito 2 6/13
```

my code is :

```
import re
dic={}
b=re.compile("chlo|mito|chlo_mito")
with open("~/A","r") as f1:
    for i in f1:
        if i.startswith("#"):continue
        a=i.replace(',',"").replace(" ","/")
        m=b.search(a)
        if m is not None:
            dic[a.strip().split("/")[0]]={}
            temp=a.strip().split("/")[1:]
            c=range(1,len(temp),2)
            for x in c:
                dic[a.strip().split("/")[0]][temp[x-1]]=temp[x]
                #print dic
lis=["chlo","mito","chlo_mito"]
for k in dic:  
    sum_value=0
    sum_values=0     
    for x in dic[k]:                        
        sum_value=sum_value+float(dic[k][x])
        for i in lis: 
        #sum_values=0 
        if i in dic[k]:
           #print i,dic[k][i]
           sum_values=sum_value+float(dic[k][i])
           print k,dic[k],i,sum_values
         #print k,dic[k]
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not really clear in describing what issue you have. But what I would do: write a function which takes as input a single line from your file and returns a dictionary with keys "chlo", "chlo_mito", "mito" and "total sum". That should make your life much easier imo.

Comment: but every line have others like "nucl" etc, the number of them is different

Answer (score 0):

Something like this code may help you:

I assume your input file is called `f_input.txt`:

```
from ast import literal_eval as eval

data = (k.rstrip().replace(',', '').split() for k in open("f_input.txt", 'r'))

for k in data:
    chlo = sum(eval(k[j+1]) for j in range(len(k)-1) if k[j] == 'chlo')
    mito = sum(eval(k[j+1]) for j in range(len(k)-1) if k[j] == 'mito')
    chlo_mito = sum(eval(k[j+1]) for j in range(len(k)-1) if k[j] == 'chlo_mito')
    total = sum(eval(k[j]) for j in range(2, len(k), 2))
    if mito == 0 and chlo_mito != 0:
        print("{0} chlo {1} chlo_mito {2} {3}/{4}".format(k[0], chlo, chlo_mito, chlo + chlo_mito, total))
    elif mito != 0 and chlo_mito == 0:
        print("{0} chlo {1} mito {2} {3}/{4}".format(k[0], chlo, mito, chlo + mito, total))
    elif mito !=0 and chlo_mito != 0:
        print("{0} chlo {1} mito {2} chlo_mito {3} {4}/{5}".format(k[0], chlo, mito, chlo_mito, chlo + mito + chlo_mito, total))
    elif mito ==0 and chlo_mito == 0:
        print("{0} chlo {1} {2}/{3}".format(k[0], chlo, chlo , total))
```

Output:

```
LOC_Os06g07630.1 chlo 2 chlo_mito 1 3/16
LOC_Os06g12160.1 chlo 7 mito 2.5 9.5/14.5
LOC_Os06g39870.1 chlo 7 7/14
LOC_Os06g48240.1 chlo 9 mito 4 13/13
LOC_Os06g48250.1 chlo 4 mito 2 6/13
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how much speed is a concern for you, but in genomics it usually is. You should probably not use much string manipulation, if you can avoid it, and as few regular expressions as possible.

Here is a version that doesn't use regexen, and tries not to spend any time constructing temporary objects. I chose to use a different output format than the one you gave, because yours would be hard to parse a second time. You can change it back easily by modifying the `.format` string.

```
Test_data = """
LOC_Os06g07630.1 cyto 8, chlo 2, extr 2, nucl 1, cysk 1, chlo_mito 1, cysk_nucl 1
LOC_Os06g12160.1 chlo 7, nucl 3, mito 2.5, cyto_mito 2
LOC_Os06g39870.1 chlo 7, cyto 4, nucl 1, E.R. 1, pero 1
LOC_Os06g48240.1 chlo 9, mito 4
LOC_Os06g48250.1 cyto 5, chlo 4, mito 2, pero 2
"""

def open_input():
    """
    Return a file-like object as input stream. In this case,
    it is a StringIO based on your test data. If you have a file
    name, use that instead.
    """

    if False:
        return open('inputfile.txt', 'r')
    else:
        import io
        return io.StringIO(Test_data)

SUM_FIELDS = set("chlo mito chlo_mito".split())

with open_input() as infile:

    for line in infile:

        line = line.strip()
        if not line: continue

        cols = line.split(maxsplit=1)
        if len(cols) != 2: continue

        test_id,remainder = cols
        out_fields = []

        fld_sum = tot_sum = 0.0

        for pair in remainder.split(', '):
            k,v = pair.rsplit(maxsplit=1)
            vf = float(v)
            tot_sum += vf

            if k in SUM_FIELDS:
                fld_sum += vf
                out_fields.append(pair)

        print("{0} {2}/{3} ({4:.0%}) {1}".format(test_id, ', '.join(out_fields), fld_sum, tot_sum, fld_sum/tot_sum))
```